# Find maximum value for a constant such that Lotka–Volterra model has a stable equilibrium

Tags: partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Given the following Lotka–Volterra model with a constant $C$:
$$\dot{x} = x(−2 + x - 3y) − C$$
$$\dot{y} = y(−2x + 3y)$$

How do I find the maximum $C$ such that the system has at least one stable equilibrium? Can I find it analytically or does it need a numerical method?

Comment: @Moo I think it is possible to find max C analytically but how? I can get that $\dot{y} = 0 \implies y = 0 \wedge y = 2/3 x  $ and substituting that into the first equation I get $ x(−2+x) = C, x(−2-x) = C $. But what are the next steps... how do I maximise C?